# In Django project method authenticate returns None

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with `authenticate()` method. It always returns None. I checked all my arguments, and they are not empty. In models, I have `USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'`, in settings I have `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.User'`. I really can't understand why it's not working.

models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create(self, username, password):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Username cant be empty')
        user = self.model(username=username)
        user.set_password(raw_password=password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_user(self, username, password):
        return self._create(username=username, password=password)

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='id')
    email = models.EmailField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    education = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

views.py

```
class UserLoginView(ObtainAuthToken):
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    def validate_username(self, username):
        if not User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('User wasn\'t found')
        print(User.objects.get(username=username).password)
        return username

    def validate(self, data):
        # authentications
        request = self.context.get('request')
        username = data.get('username') # test_name
        password = data.get('password') # newpassword11
        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password, request=request)
            print(user)
            if not user:
                raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid password')
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('You have to type you\'re mail and password')
        data['user'] = user
        return data
```

Comment: The `new_pas = make_password(password)` makes no sense, since the `authenticate` already will check the hashing.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I know. I was trying to find error

Comment: can you share the `UserManager` you used? and if you implemented a custom authentication backend, share that as well? Please [edit] the question.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, sure. I added UserManager and i didn't use any custom authentication backend*

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the model to this:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    .....
```

after send post request to url routing to `UserLoginView` view with `username` and `password` at the post body got Json something like this at the response:

```
{"token":"30e0215a5f4cc521203a633452d63995d8f1fa77"}
```

When used `AbstractBaseUser` instead of `AbstractUser` be careful to implement all requirements of Django user model.

Tips: Do not forget to make the `DRF Authentication` settings correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `users` field,  called `is_active`. **Django** allows to `login` only when user is active.

P.S. Thank to everyone, who tried to help :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may be struggling with this error, I was facing the same issue and discovered that what I was missing was declaring the auth settings in the settings file.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "user.User"

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```